# Prove that $f:G\rightarrow G:(r,s)\rightarrow (0,s)$ is a group homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be the group $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^{\ast }$ with the operation $(r,s)(m,n)=(r+sm,sn)$. I need to prove that $f:G\rightarrow G:(r,s)\rightarrow (0,s)$ is an endomorphism with $f^{2}=f$. 
Also is $f:G\rightarrow G:(r,s)\rightarrow (r,1)$ an endomorphism?

I know that in order to prove that f is an endomorphism, i need to show that f is a group homomorphism. My issue is the actual group G and the operation defined on it. The notation confuses me and thus i'm stuck.

Appreciate all the help

Comment: $f((r,s)\cdot(m,n))=f(r+sm,sn)=(0,sn)=f(r,s)\cdot f(m,n)$. Hopefully that can get you started. Are you taking for granted that this operation is associative and inverses exist?

Comment: @IanColey: thanks Ian, but if you dont mind, could you explain why we need the $f^{2}=f$ condition?

Comment: I'll write a full answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated above, we see that
$$
f((r,s)\cdot(m,n))=f(r+sm,sn)=(0,sn)=(0,s)\cdot(0,n)=f(r,s)\cdot f(m,n)
$$
so it is a proper group homomorphism, assuming the group operation is appropriate. To see that $f^2=f$,
$$
f^2(r,s)=f(0,s)=(0,s)=f(r,s)
$$
for any $(r,s)\in G$.

For the second part, we check to see if it's an actual homomorphism.

$$
f((r,s)\cdot(m,n))=f(r+sm,sn)=f(r+sm,1)\neq (r+m,1)=(r,1)\cdot(m,1)=f(r,s)\cdot f(m,n),
$$
so multiplication isn't preserved under $f$ and it fails to be an endomorphism.

Comment: thank you again!!! question: how do you go from $f^{2}(r,s)$ to $f(0,s)$? meaning: why are the two equal?

Comment: Sorry,
$$
f^2(r,s)=f(f(r,s))=f(0,s).
$$
If I can't clear anything else up, go ahead and mark this one answered!

Comment: Any time!$\ \ \ \ $

Comment: Ian, I have another question on abstract algebra. Would you mind helping me with it through chat?

Comment: Sure! I don't know how to initiate that, so you'll have to start

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10646/discussion-between-dome-and-ian-coley)